# How to add color buttons on grid view asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have done making check box as i have taken the boolean variable as grid view in visual studio automatically show check box in grid view .it is an update in vs2012 , but vs2010 .you have create it manually.but i want to show color button instead of check box .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RowDataBound` event of `gridview` as follows

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       //check for a particular value
       // change the color of button after finding button in the row
    }
 }
```